# How to remove a letter from a particular position in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was practicing the wildcard Character.And I came to know about the '^' character, which helps to find a word which doesn't contain that specific letter with which the wildcard character is used.

My query to find a name from vEmployee, which doesn't contain a letter 'Y' in it's second letter of the name and whose name starts with 'D'...

```
USE AdventureWorks2012

SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.vEmployee
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'D[^Y]%'


BusinessEntityID    Title   FirstName   MiddleName  LastName
8                   NULL    Diane           L       Margheim
16                  NULL    David           M       Bradley
52                  NULL    Doris           M       Hartwig
53                  NULL    Diane           R       Glimp
56                  NULL    Denise          H       Smith
61                  NULL    Diane           H       Tibbott
70                  NULL    David           J       Ortiz
90                  NULL    Danielle        C       Tiedt
118                 NULL    Don             L       Hall
127                 NULL    David           P       Hamilton
```

But my question is how can we find out a name whose third letter doesn't contain 'A'.
I tried the query like this

```
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.vEmployee  
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'D[^^A]%'
```

but it didn't get me a correct answer nor it showed any error.

So,what's the answer???

Comment: Note:  your title is not consistent with your question.  Can you change the title to something more appropriate (by editing the question)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `_` wildcard.  It matches exactly one letter:

```
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.vEmployee
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'D_[^A]%'
```

Or, if you want not Y and not A:

```
SELECT *
FROM HumanResources.vEmployee
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'D[^Y][^A]%'
```

As a note:  The expression `LIKE 'D[^^A]` returns all names where the first character is a "D" and the second is neither "^" nor "A".  The carat only has special meaning when preceded by `[`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression

```
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'D[A-Z][^A]%'
```